# swift - I want to go back to previous viewController which in TabBarController

Tags: swift, uitabbarcontroller

I want to go back to user viewController which in TabBarController after signed up, but when I go back to the controller in tabBarController there is no tabBar at bottom.

Here is my Code

```
 let MyPage = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("MyViewController")

 presentViewController(MyPage!, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

MyViewController is the fifth view controller in TabBarController

Please tell me  how to go to a view controller in tabBarController,Thank you very much!

Comment: MyViewController is TabBarController?

Comment: @rnsjtngus MyViewController is the fifth view controller in TabBarController

Comment: do u have navigationController at each tab?

Comment: If u have navigationController at each tab, replace presentViewController function to self.navigationController?.pushViewController function

Comment: I don't have navigationController.

Comment: if u use presentViewController function, ur new viewController doesn't have tabBarController. So u can't show taBarController's tabBar.

Comment: make new tabBarController if u want use tabBar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using presentViewController function, use         dismissViewControllerAnimated function.

replace

```
self.presentViewController(MyPage, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

to

```
self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
```

Comment: I want to show the TabBar when I go back to this controller, and I didn't find a member of tabBarController called tabBar, I'm using Xcode 7 now.

Comment: u have to dismiss ur current viewController. not present new viewController

Comment: I change my answer. check it

Comment: Good. plz choose my answer :)